# How to widget-test FutureBuilder with unresolved Future

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I wonder how I can test the case when a future is not yet completed in flutter widget tests.

The widget should show a spinner as long as the future is unresolved.

I tride this test case:

```
testWidgets(
  'should show a spinner when loading',
  (WidgetTester tester) async {
    when(valueRepository.getValues())
        .thenAnswer((_) => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 30), () => []));
    await tester.pumpWidget(withApp(ValueListPage(
      valueRepository: valueRepository,
    )));

    await tester.pumpAndSettle(
        Duration(seconds: 10), EnginePhase.build, Duration(minutes: 1));

    expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget);
  },
);
```

Result: The future is resolved and the expectation fails.

Note: withApp initializes an App with localization. Because of that I have to call `tester.pumpAndSettle()` to wait for l10n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a working solution with fakeAsync:

```
testWidgets(
  'should show a spinner when loading',
  (WidgetTester tester) async {
      when(valueRepository.getValues()).thenAnswer(
          (_) => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => []));
      await tester.pumpWidget(withApp(ValueListPage(
        valueRepository: valueRepository,
      )));

      await tester.pump();

      expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsNothing);
  },
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
testWidgets(
  'should show a spinner when loading',
  (WidgetTester tester) async {
    tester.runAsync(() async {
      when(valueRepository.getValues())
          .thenAnswer((_) => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 30), () => []));
      await tester.pumpWidget(withApp(ValueListPage(
        valueRepository: valueRepository,
      )));

      await tester.pumpAndSettle(
          Duration(seconds: 10), EnginePhase.build, Duration(minutes: 1));

      expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget);
    });
  },
);
```

Tests run with fakeAsync by default and some async code doesn't run properly with fakeAsync.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use completer to stay the AsyncSnapshot on waiting.
for example:

```
testWidgets('should show a spinner when loading',(WidgetTester tester) async {

    Completer completer = Completer();
    when(valueRepository.getValues())
       .thenAnswer((_) => completer.future);
    await tester.pumpWidget(withApp(ValueListPage(
    valueRepository: valueRepository,
    )));

    expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget); 
 },
);
```