# Flaky widget tests in Flutter for more than one test in a file

Tags: flutter, testing, widget

I've implemented two widget tests. Each one works fine separately, although executed altogether always bring exception for the seconds test. If I swap the order, the second test in a file fails as well. Tests are pretty simple, so I have no clue where to go. I tried [a solution for similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69004451/1714102) - without success.

In tests I'm trying to find out if the icons of the widget are visible on a screen with `hitTestable`.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:circle_ui_navigator/circle_ui_navigator.dart';
import 'package:circle_ui_navigator/src/icons_circle/tappable_icon.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

import 'test_utils.dart';

const iPhone13Size = Size(375, 667);
const samsungS20LandscapeSize = Size(800, 360);

void main() {
  testWidgets("""GIVEN landscape and widget centered on a screen 
  WHEN 5 actions 
  THEN 6 icons found""", (tester) async {
    await tester.binding.setSurfaceSize(samsungS20LandscapeSize);
    await tester.loadCircleNavigatorWidget(
      actionsCount: 5,
      center: Point(
        samsungS20LandscapeSize.width / 2,
        samsungS20LandscapeSize.height / 2,
      ),
    );
    await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(milliseconds: animationDuration));

    expect(find.byType(TappableIcon).hitTestable(), findsNWidgets(6));
    await tester.binding.setSurfaceSize(null);
  });

  testWidgets('''GIVEN portrait and widget centered on a screen WHEN 9 actions THEN 10 icons found''', (tester) async {
    await tester.binding.setSurfaceSize(iPhone13Size);
    await tester.loadCircleNavigatorWidget(
      actionsCount: 9,
      center: Point(iPhone13Size.width / 2, iPhone13Size.height / 2),
    );
    await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(milliseconds: animationDuration));

    expect(find.byType(TappableIcon).hitTestable(), findsNWidgets(10));
    await tester.binding.setSurfaceSize(null);
  });
}
```

Wider scope for the issue is [here on github](https://github.com/Swirastlynn/circle_ui_navigator/blob/c450414a0607d29389e02cb013e5b7f5ff8acd6e/test/widget/circular_ui_navigator_test.dart)

The test framework error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure was thrown running a test:
Expected: exactly 10 matching nodes in the widget tree
  Actual: _HitTestableFinder:<zero widgets with type "TappableIcon" (considering only hit-testable
ones) (ignoring offstage widgets)>
   Which: means none were found but some were expected
```

Have anyone overcome such a problem?